# How to efficiently Raycast outside of main thread?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

In my project I'm trying to generate a heightmap of a mesh.
Initially I used a bunch of Unitys build-in Physics-Raycasts which worked, but also blocked the main thread, causing everything to freeze until the Raycast was done.

To fix this I tried moving the Raycast into a seperate thread, which Unity doesn't allow, because of internal Physics.
Since my mesh doesn't move I started implementing my own Raycast outside the main thread and it worked, but it's quite slow.

My Code currently checks for every x and z coordinate if a triangle contains the the (x, z) point. if it does it computes the height. if the computed height is higher than the previously computed height the value is overwritten.

```cs
// calculate topView/heightmap with topdown raycasting
float[,] topView = new float[xArray.Length, zArray.Length];
for(int i=0;i<xArray.Length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<zArray.Length;j++){
        float y = float.PositiveInfinity;
        bool isHit = false;

        for(int k=0;k<triangles.Length;k+=3){
            if(Math.Abs(normals[k/3].y) < 0.01) continue;

            Vector3 p0 = vertices[triangles[k]];
            Vector3 p1 = vertices[triangles[k+1]];
            Vector3 p2 = vertices[triangles[k+2]];

            // check if triangle is important
            float s = (p0.x - p2.x) * (zArray[j] - p2.z) - (p0.z - p2.z) * (xArray[i] - p2.x);
            float t = (p1.x - p0.x) * (zArray[j] - p0.z) - (p1.z - p0.z) * (xArray[i] - p0.x);

            if ((s < 0) != (t < 0) && s != 0 && t != 0) continue;

            float d = (p2.x - p1.x) * (zArray[j] - p1.z) - (p2.z - p1.z) * (xArray[i] - p1.x);
            if(d == 0 || (d < 0) == (s + t <= 0)){
                y = Math.Min(y, (xArray[i] * normals[k/3].x + zArray[j] * normals[k/3].z - Vector3.Dot(normals[k/3], p0)) / normals[k/3].y);
                isHit = true;
            }
        }
                        
        if(isHit){
            topView[i, j] = -y;
        }
    }
}
```

(`normals` are the normal-vectors of each triangle formed by the verticies)

What can I do to improve the performance of my code?
Is there a even better way of doing this?

Comment: You should try out the Job system and [`RaycastCommand`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastCommand.html) .. and then there is [DRCS](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/dynamic-raycast-system-2-0-c-jobs-123768) ... last time I used that I head to refactor it a lot though to fix some performance issues :'D

Comment: managed to improve it by "drawing" the triangles into the 2d array instead of checking each triangle for each point